# Copying Data Between Two Struct Array Variables

Tags: c, variables, struct, char

I'm building a program that takes in names of users along with there Date of Birth and prints out the youngest user. I'm using two structs to do this:

```
struct date   
{ int day;      
  int month;    
  int year;     
};         

struct person     
{ char name[80];
  struct date birth;
};
```

And two variables:

```
struct person p[5], final;
```

The users are put into Variable p. Then I for loop putting the first user data into final then comparing everyone else with final. What should be left in final is the data if the youngest user which I print out.

However, when I try to put the name of p into final I get this compiler error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[80]’ from type ‘char *’
    final.name = p[i].name;
```

Can someone help me please!

Thanks!!!

edit:

I copy the data over like this (sorry for missing this out earlier):

```
final.name = p[i].name;
final.birth.day = p[i].birth.day;
final.birth.month = p[i].birth.month;
final.birth.year = p[i].birth.year;
```

Comment: Do you want to copy the string or the entire struct?

Comment: Laimh101,  Please edit your question and show the code which makes this assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign to an array like that. Use [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) instead.

```
strcpy(final.name, p[i].name);
```

Remember to include `string.h`.